# Rails 4 STI inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I'm using single table inheritance successfully like so:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end

class Purchase < Transaction
end

class Refund < Transaction
end
```

The abbreviated/simplified PurchaseController looks like this:

```
class PurchaseController < TransactionController
  def new
    @transaction = @order.purchases.new(type: type)
  end

  def create
    @transaction = @order.purchases.new secure_params
    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to @order
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The abbreviated/simplified Purchase model looks like this:

```
class Purchase < Transaction
  attr_accessor :cc_number, :cc_expiry, :cc_csv
end
```

**What I'm trying to do** is have different variations of a purchase, for instance a cash purchase & a cheque purchase. The issue is I'm not sure how to call the model for that variation.

For example:

```
class Cash < Purchase
  attr_accessor :receipt_no
end

class CashController < TransactionController
  def new
    # This will use the Purchase.rb model so that's no good because I need the Cash.rb model attributes
    @transaction = @order.purchases.new(type: type)

    # This gives me the following error:
    # ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: Purchase is not a subclass of Cash
    @transaction = Cash.new(type: 'Purchase', order: @order.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: serious deja vu here.

Comment: @sevenseacat, yep couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, this works fine for me:

```
@order.purchases.new(type: "Cash") # returns a new Cash instance
```

You can also push a new Cash on to the association if you are ready to save it:

```
@order.purchases << Cash.new
```

Or you can define a separate association in Order:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cashes
end

@order.cashes.new # returns a new Cash instance
```

Comment: In the end I just created a bunch of different namespaced types. I.e: `type: Purchase::Online` & `type: Purchase::Cash`...

Answer (score 1):

**Class**

Maybe I'm being obtuse, but perhaps you'll be willing to not make the `Purchase` type an inherited class?

The problem I see is that you're calling `Cash.new`, when really you may be better to include all the functionality you require in the `Purchase` model, which will then be able to be re-factored afterwards.

Specifically, why don't you just include your own `type` attribute in your `Purchase` model, which you'll then be able to use with the following setup:

```
#app/controllers/cash_controller.rb
class CashController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @transaction = Purchase.new 
   end

   def create
      @transaction = Purchase.new transaction_params
      @transaction.type ||= "cash"
   end

   private

   def cash_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

The only downside to this would be that if you wanted to include different [business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) for each type of purchase, you'll still want to use your inherited model. However, you could simply split the functionality in the `before_create` callback:

```
#app/models/puchase.rb
class Purchase < Transaction
   before_create :set_type

   private

   def set_type
      if type =="cash"
        # do something here
      else
        # do something here
      end
   end
end
```

As such, right now, I think your use of two separate models (`Cash` and `Cheque`) will likely be causing much more of an issue than is present. Although I'd love to see how you could inherit from an inherited `Model`, what I've provided is something you also may wish to look into

Comment: Hey @richpeck, the reason I have them split into their own models is because they have different attributes and validations and I'd end up with too many conditional validations and unused attributes if I kept it all in one model. However, the actual data that gets persisted to the database is the same independent of purchase method. Also, the `type` attribute is reserved for STI for my two types of transactions(`Purchase` & `Refund`) so I'd have to use a different attribute name which is fine but things start getting messy.